# Was the reality stone used to develop BARF?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

It will take several years or even decades before real-world VR/AR will develop into B.A.R.F. of 2016 MCU as seen in Stark’s launch. And it has improved into a greater, more realistic drone-reliant B.A.R.F. in 2024 MCU. The reality stone is basically B.A.R.F. in a stone, with no drones, and no video editors/green screen work needed, so I can assume that the reality stone is what B.A.R.F. would be in a few decades when it is 100% developed.

Did the presence of the reality stone play a part in the creation or development of B.A.R.F.?

Comment: the stone no longer exists by the time far from home happens, and they are still using the technology. I very much doubt its possible for that reason alone.

Comment: This happens when you don't watch the movie in chronological order and don't notice the chronological order both at the same time. Apologies if I've been rude.

Comment: What about the MCU films makes you think they mirror real-world technological advancements? They *clearly* have superior technology, so there's no reason to think the Reality Stone would be needed to produce this.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be no, Stark and Stark Industries never came into direct contact with the Reality Stone until Avengers: Infinity War.

In the MCU, the Reality Stone had been locked away for a very long time, since the war between the Asgards and the Dark Elves.  It was only recently discovered due to the convergence (of realities?  of realms?  forget the term they used) causing weird wormholes that lead Jane Foster to the Aether (the container for the Reality Stone).

After Thor: Dark World the Reality stone was given to the Collector on Knowhere to hold onto it.  It was held here until Thanos got ahold of it in Infinity War.

In this timeline, there was no way for anyone from Stark Industries to get ahold of it to use it for their technology.

Answer (score 2):

#### No

[B.A.R.F](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Binarily_Augmented_Retro-Framing) was created by Quentin Beck before he knew the reality stone even existed.

We know this because Tony uses this technology in [Captain America: Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War).

Comment: It was possible for Beck to had learned about the reality stone, since `Thor 2` (where the aether was used in greenwich) predates `Civil War` (3 year gap).